Why are defect formation energies tabulated in terms of the change in enthalpy?
I've come across the defect energy formation equation of a defect $D$ in the charge state $q$, given by
$$\Delta H_{D,q}(E_F,\mu)=\left [ E_{D,q}-E_H \right ]+\sum_{i=1}^{n}N_i\mu_i+qE_F+E_{\textrm{corr}}$$
From classical thermodynamics, we have
$$dU(S,V,\left\{ N_i \right\}_{i=1}^n) = T \, dS - P \, dV + \sum_{i=1}^{n} \mu_i \, dN_i$$
$$dH(S,P,\left\{ N_i \right\}_{i=1}^n) = T \, dS + V \, dP + \sum_{i=1}^{n} \mu_i \, dN_i$$
Do we assume constant pressure conditions and a negligible PV-work term in order to justify tabulating defect formation energy in terms of enthalpy?
